# How to convert Pojo to parquet?

Tags: java, parquet

I want to convert the below class into parquet format. Is there any Library? I don't want to do pojo->avro->parquet. All I want is pojo -> parquet.

```
public class Hello {
   int x;
   HashMap<String, String> map;
   ArrayList<Integer> list;
}
```